# Ajax response with Javascript returns Undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to pass a variable from a form field to a function which in returns checks if the value exists from the database and returns either exists or not_exist, but this it returns undefined.

```
registerButtonAction.addEventListener('click', function() {
        disableRegisterButton();
        var getRegisterUsername = document.getElementById('registerUsername').value;

        var confirmUser = validatedUser(getRegisterUsername);
        alert(confirmUser); //alerts undefined instead of exist, or not_exist
        if (confirmUser === 'not_exist') {
            alert('Okay');
        }
    });

function checkRegisterUsername(getRegisterUsername){
    $.ajax({

        type:"post",
        url: "accounts/users/checkUsername/"+getRegisterUsername,
        data:{getRegisterUsername:getRegisterUsername},
        success: function(data){
            if(data==='exists'){
                var a='exists';
                return a;
            }else if(data==='not_exist'){
                var a='not_exist';
                return a;
            }else if(data==='navigation_error'){
                enableRegisterButton();
                document.getElementById('resistrationStatus').innerHTML="<small style='font-size: 15px; color: #ac2925'><i class='fa fa-info-circle'></i> FATAL ERROR OCCURRED, RELOAD PAGE</small>";
            }else{
                enableRegisterButton();
                document.getElementById('resistrationStatus').innerHTML="<small style='font-size: 15px; color: #ac2925'><i class='fa fa-info-circle'></i> FATAL ERROR OCCURRED, RELOAD PAGE</small>";
            }
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("Error Occured, Check your connection and try again.");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You could check via DevTools what is your request returning, maybe it's a mal formatted request or your backend is not answering properly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Looks like there are cases in your function which don't return anything. The default return value is ```undefined```

Comment: backend answers correctly, if I try to use an existing username, it returns exist, else not_exist.....

Comment: @RobertKibet this is a duplicate. You are not writing remotely correct code but you will in time. You need to learn about asynchronous programming.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your `validateUser(..)` function will call your ajax. In your case i think your ajax call isn't finish yet when alert is fired.

Try to move this part at the end of ajax's success. Or you can either add `async: false` as paremeter of ajax. With async to false it will wait for the end of the call before move on.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that `validatedUser` and `checkRegisterUsername` are the same function, and you forgot to change the names.

AJAX calls are tipically asynchronous. This means that you can't wait for a return value: `success` function will be executed when the AJAX call will succeed, but in a separate context.

Even if you make the AJAX call synchronous, `return` in a success/error callback is meaningless. Also, the return value you are trying to catch is the one of `checkRegisterUsername`, that does not have a return status at all, that's why is undefined.

To achieve what you want, try to put the `alert` part inside the `success` handler, i.e. instead of `return a` write `alert(a)` and see what happens.